# prevent user to access login page in django when already logged in?

Tags: django, authentication

```
def admin_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request,username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
        if(user.is_superuser):
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse("dashboard"))
        else:
            messages.info(request, "invalid credentials")
        return redirect(reverse("admin"))
     
return render(request,'login.html')
```

this is mylogin function for admin , how to prevent user to access login page once logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the user who is requesting is authenticated and if so, you can redirect him to another page. You can check user if he is authenticated like this

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # redirect
```

so your view function will be like this

```py
def admin_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse("admin")) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request,username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if(user.is_superuser):
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse("dashboard"))
            else:
                messages.info(request, "invalid credentials")
            return redirect(reverse("admin"))
         
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

Comment: changed my view function but it showing errors like  This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.

Comment: Change `return redirect(reverse("admin"))` to `return redirect(reverse("dashboard"))`

Answer (score 0):

do this in beginning of your login function

```
def user_login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if(request.user.is_authenticated):
        print('user authenticated')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```